# HttpClient empty member variable although it was assigned

Tags: angular

In Angular4 a request to endpoint is made and an array of `Post`s is returned from it. Headers are correct. And inside the `'next'` in `subscribe()` `data` gets assigned correctly, and the `console.log` shows it. But `this.posts` is empty or rather undefined, as you can see in the `console.log` of posts2.

What is wrong and how do I solve it?

I'm thinking a promise that is fulfilled after the instance is initialized. How could this be?
Or it races past the if statement and returns an undefined value before the request is even made.

How can I not make it do that?

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class PostService {

  private serviceUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/posts';
  private posts: Post[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  // get all posts or all posts by channel
  list(channel?: string|undefined): Post[] {
    if (channel) {
      this.http.get<Array<Post>>(this.serviceUrl + '?channel=' + channel).subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log('data', data);
          this.posts = data;
          console.log('posts1', this.posts);
          return data;
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.http.get<Array<Post>>(this.serviceUrl).subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log('data', data);
          this.posts = data;
          console.log('posts1', this.posts);
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    }

    console.log('posts2', this.posts);
    return this.posts;
  }

  // get one post by Id
  get(id: string): Post {
    let post: Post = new Post();
    this.http.get<Post>(this.serviceUrl + '/' + id).subscribe(
      data => {
        post = data;
      }
    );
    return post;
  }

  create(post: Post): void {
    this.http.post<any>(this.serviceUrl, post).subscribe();
  }

  update(post: Post): Post {
    let r: Post = new Post();
    this.http.put<Post>(this.serviceUrl, post).subscribe(
      data => {
        r = data;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
    return r;
  }

  remove(id: string): void {
    this.http.delete(this.serviceUrl + '/' + id).subscribe();
  }

}

export class Post {
  id: string;
  authorId: string;
  title: string;
  slug: string;
  body: string;
  channels: string[];
  createdAt: string;
}
```

Result

```
post.service.ts:40 posts2 undefined
post.service.ts:30 data (2) [{…}, {…}]
post.service.ts:32 posts1 (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
console.log('posts2', this.posts);
```

Returns undefined because it is executed BEFORE the data is returned.

Http requests are asynchronous so the request is made and AT SOME LATER POINT IN TIME, the value is returned and the subscribe callback is executed.

Here is a picture with numbers showing the execution order.

[image]

**Using a Service**

Because of the way this works, you will most often see the service execute the request and return the observable. And the CALLER code performs the subscribe and then can know when the value is returned.

My service call looks like this:

```
getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl)
                    .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And my component code looks like this:

```
getMovies(): void {
    this.movieService.getMovies()
        .subscribe(
            (movies: IMovie[]) => {
                this.movies = movies;
            },
            (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

**Using a Resolver**

Another option is to use a resolver. If you build a resolver you can ensure that the data is retrieved BEFORE a route is displayed.

Here is an example of a resolver:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { IMovie } from './movie';
import { MovieService } from './movie.service';

@Injectable()
export class MovieResolver implements Resolve<IMovie> {

    constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IMovie> {
        const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
        return this.movieService.getMovie(+id);
    }
}
```

When tied to a route, this code will execute (and the data will be retrieved) BEFORE the routed component's template is displayed. This may get you to what you want.

Comment: Yes and how do I not make it do that? In your image this.products is assigned later, outside the member function. You're also not using subscribe() but do() and catch(). And you return an Observable, but I return a Post[]. In my script it's all happening inside the function. And I also tried to call this.list() in the constructor, the result is just 2 times of the same. Only after I navigate to a different route and return to the original route which is accessing the PostService's posts variable I'm getting the post member updated.

Comment: I was interrupted and did not have a chance to finish my post. I just finished it now. Does that help? And you can't "not make it do that". HTTP *is* asynchronous: request ... and some time later ... response. This is not an "Angular" thing, but how Http works.

Comment: That's what we get for living in an eventful world. Thank you. So in conclusion: In services return promises (or rather they're called Observables now, because they're serious about MVC now), subscribe to the service methods when you actually need data.